# How to make pagination using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made a pagination page using bootstrap, ajax and jQuery. But I got a problem in viewing it. I created a button 1,2,3,...... and a container div. I initially displayed 5 rows using jQuery and Ajax. But when I click on 2(second button) button, new 5 rows are displayed along with the previous 5 rows displayed initially in a container div. The new rows gets added below the previous rows as I clicked on buttons. How can I remove the previous rows when I clicked on buttons.

The given below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
  </div>
  <ul id="btns"  class="pagination"></ul>
  </body>
<script>
            var current_page=1;
            function change_page(page_no)
              {
                student(page_no);
              }
           $(document).ready(function()
              {        
                student(1);
             }); 
            function student(page_no){
            var data1 = ""
            var total_rows=""       
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data:{ "page": page_no},
                url: "ajax_connect.php",             
                dataType: "html",
            success: function(rows) 
            {  
               console.log(JSON.parse(rows))
                rows = JSON.parse(rows)
                total_rows=rows.data;
                table(total_rows);
                total_buttons=rows.count/5;
                total_buttons=total_buttons+1;
                button(total_buttons);
                   }
               }) 
             }

function table(total_rows)
     {
        html+= "<div class='table-responsive' id='keywords'>";
        html+= "<table  class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
        html+=  "<thead>" +
                "<tr>" +
                  "<th><a id='emp_id'>Employee Id</a></th>" +
                  "<th><a id='emp_name'>Employee Name</a></th>" +
                  "<th><a id='email'>Email</a></th>" +
                  "<th><a id='message'>Message</a></th>" +
                  "<th><a id='date'>Date</a></th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</thead>";
        //function table(total_rows)
        for (var i in total_rows)
         {
          var row = total_rows[i];
          //var row = rows[i];
          var employee_id = row[0];
          var employee_name = row[1];
          var email = row[2];
          var message = row[3];
          var date = row[4];
          html+= "<tr>" +
                    "<td width='25%'>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
                    "<td width='25%'>" + employee_name + "</td>" +
                    "<td width='25%'>" + email + "</td>" +
                    "<td width='25%'>" + message + "</td>" +
                    "<td width='25%'>" + date + "</td>" +
                 "</tr>";                  
         }
        html+= "</table>";
        html+= "</div>";
        $(".container").html(html);
  }
  function button(total_pages)
    {      
     var buttons = "<ul class='pagination' align='center' >"
     for (var i = 1; i<=total_pages; i ++)
      {
       buttons +=  "<li><a id= "+i+" onclick= 'change_page(" +i+ ")' href= '#'>"+i+"</a></li>"
      }
     buttons += "</ul>";
     $(".pagination").html(buttons);
    }
  </script>
  </html>
```

Ignore the ajax url part they are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not declared Your html using var keyword inside a function, its declared in global scope. 
Each time You run the function table() the content of html is extended with += assignment.

Your fix would be in first line of table() function

```
var html = "<div class='table-responsive' id='keywords'>";
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. On appending new rows if you want a fresh table clear the previously appended stuff in html and then append new stuff.